# getting files that were saved on the server (node.js)

Tags: node.js, dynamic, server, readfile

so i have a shopping app. when ever a client finish an order a receipt is in the server under "public/receipts" with the ID name of the order. my server is depolyed on heroku so i dont have access to the file. i have tried to make a dynamic API which will open a new tab with the receipt according to the order id of the receipt. for example: "localhost:4422/getReceipt/:orderId" so i will get different receipts according to the "orderId" but im not sure how to do it. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku, like [Docker](https://www.docker.com/), has an [ephemeral](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) filesystem. This means you can't rely on it as persistent storage.

I would recommend using a cloud file storage product such as [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) or perhaps the [Heroku ecosystem](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) offers solutions for this.

Then you'd upload the receipt to cloud storage instead of the local file system and retrieve it by order id.